# Pass data from on component to another react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a questionnaire and send an request to get all data back from the database, that match the answers. I then want to use the data in another component to display the results.

```
 <div className='row justify-content-end mt-3 pb-5'>
   <div className='btn btn-primary btn-block rounded shadow-sm result' onClick=this.getSelectedOptions}>Ergebnisanalyse</div>
</div>
```

My onClick triggers the function in a class component called "ImpactAnalysis" where i get my results back as an array of objects. Then i want to display the result in a class component "ResultPage"

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass props for one component to another?

Comment: Where are the two components in relation to each other? Is one a child of the other? Are they siblings? Please include details/an example of the structure.

Comment: They are siblings: 

-pages
   - ImpactAnalysis
   - ResultPage

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like this:

```
<ResultPage data={impactAnalysisResults} />
```

Then you will have this array on your ResultPage component.

```
const ResultPage = ({data}) => {
    const { impactAnalysisResults } = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply send those data in a component as props. to send props to a component add key name and pair value with it. As example

```
<ResultPage data={impactAnalysisResults} />
```

from ResultPage catch values like

```
function ResultPage ({data}) {
    console.log(data) //check data object sent from parent component
    return (
    //show your data from 'data' props
    <div>{data}</div>
   )
}
```